# Hide the NSDatePicker with NSClickGestureRecognizer

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am developing an app in Objective-C with Cocoa.
I have an NSDatePicker in my app, which I would like to hide after clicking anywhere in the application.
I have:

```
NSView *mainView - main NSView containing all application elements. 
NSDatePicker *datePicker - picker which I would like to hide.
```

And I am trying to do it this way:

```
NSClickGestureRecognizer *click = [[NSClickGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action:@selector(hideCalendar:)];
[mainView addGestureRecognizer: click];

...

-(void) hideCalendar:(NSGestureRecognizer*)rec{
[datePicker setHidden:YES];
}
```

I know there can be only one NSGestureRecognizer of the each type and every element in mainView stops working as it should. So is there a way to call original action of NSClickGestureRecognizer in the hideCalendar: function?

I also tried implement my own NSGestureRecognizer. But to be honest, I don't really know which functions to implement.

How should I hide the datePicker when I click somewhere outside of it while preserving the original behaviour of the rest of the view elements?

Best regards!

Comment: Rather than hide it, why not animate it off the visible view area?

Comment: "there can be only one NSGestureRecognizer of the each type" do you have a link?

Comment: "every element in mainView stops working as it should" simple subclasses of `NSControl` don't use `NSGestureRecognizer`.

Comment: What do you mean by "original action of NSClickGestureRecognizer"?

Comment: Try `click.delaysPrimaryMouseButtonEvents = false`.

Comment: @Willeke
https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/make-a-custom-uigesturerecognizer-in-objective-c-b9099fd8cfa3 -> "Another important thing to note is that views can have multiple gesture recognizers as long as they are not the same type of gesture and as long it makes sense for the purpose of the view."

I have a PopUpButtons in mainView. When I don't add NSClickGestureRecognizer they work as they should. However, when I add it, they do not respond to clicks anymore.

Comment: @Willeke I think that Your suggestion (click.delaysPrimaryMouseButtonEvents = false) solved my problem :D
Thank You!

Comment: You can have multiple `NSClickGestureRecognizer`s and `NSPopUpButton` doesn't use a `NSClickGestureRecognizer`.